# Get file path from Document directory - Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, path

Actually, I'm relying on full file path for security options (for that I need file path for it to be stored in keychain). It means that when I rebuild the app (or when it will get an update when published to AppStore), these features are broken due to bundle ID change in file path.

I've thought of a solution for this issue : get file path only from Documents directory (/Documents/.../.../myFile.pdf) rather than full path (/var/mobile/.../...). Is there a way of doing this ?

Alternatively is there any other solution to my issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Use `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);` and save only what's after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Larme and @user3182143, I've found a solution : getting Documents path and splitting file path by 2 : one part before Document directory

```
bundlePath = [documentsDirectory stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

and the other part with

```
documentsPath = [documentsDirectory lastPathComponent];
...
filepath = [documentsPath stringByApendingPathComponent:@"myFile.pdf"];
```

If I need the full path, I'll get it by

```
fullPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filepath];
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the File Path from Document Directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strFileName]];
```